# How to create Word document in WinRT

Tags: c#, wpf, ms-word, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I'm currently developing application using WinRT/C#. It is second version, first was developed on WPF. In application I need to generate some reports and export them into MS Word document. 
In first version of application I used MS Office Interop to export reports in MS Word, but in WinRT there is no support of MS Office Interop. Is there any simple way to create MS Word document in WinRT? (I know there are third party libraries like [Syncfusion for WinRT](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/winrt) but I would prefer to not use them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to use MS Office interop from a Windows Store app. You could use [Open XML SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124), though. It is also [available on NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml) and seems to be WinRT compatible.

Using it won't be as easy as working with interop classes and you'll only be able to create XML based `docx` files, not binary `doc` files. On the other hand your users won't need to have Word installed and they'll be able to open the files in other Office suites like OpenOffice or LibreOffice. There's a [set of tutorials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc850833%28v=office.14%29) available on MSDN to get you started.

Comment: I don't know why this is marked as answer. The open xml sdk will not work with winRT. Completely misleading.

Answer (score 3):

There is a free solution that consiste to format your document in rtf.

For this i create a new librairy to help a developper to create a document compatible with word.

you can find this there : https://github.com/crogun/WinRTF-For-WinRT

the code is open source, and you can extend it if you want.